# use day period to plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use day period to plot the data. I used to plot it in "year" period.
It was worked. But change to day, it did not work.

the time I used is this format 2018-12-06 05:19:00

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline
plt.title("Fuel in Australia")

plt.xlabel("DATE") 
plt.ylabel("price")
plt.scatter(df_diesel['DATE'], df_diesel['price'])
plt.show()
```

it returned TypeError: invalid type promotion

Answer (score 0):

If `df_diesel` is a Pandas dataframe, I suggest you use the `df.plot()` function, as it would suit you better:

```
df_diesel[['DATE', 'price']].plot()
plt.show()
```

In regards to your error message, it would be much appreciated if you explained what you mean by "change to day" (resampled frequency?) and also maybe give a small example of how your data looks like. Be sure that the `DATE` column is datetime-types, it could probably be that.

Comment: It is the data type problem for that reason the data could not plot successfully.